# Position a small console window to the bottom left of the screen?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, console, position

As the title says, I want to position it to the bottom left corner of the screen. Here's the code I have so far:

```
    Console.WindowWidth = 50
    Console.WindowHeight = 3
    Console.BufferWidth = 50
    Console.BufferHeight = 3
    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkMagenta
    Console.Title = "My Title"
    Console.WriteLine("")
    Console.Write(" Press any key to close this window ...")

    Console.ReadKey()
```

Comment: Dim x = 0
Dim y = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - console.height
console.Location = New Size(x, y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Console.WindowTop` and `Console.WindowWidth` of the `System.Console` class to set the location of the console window.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.windowtop(v=vs.110).aspx) is an example on MSDN

The `BufferHeight` and `BufferWidth` property gets/sets the number of rows and columns to be displayed.

`WindowHeight` and `WindowWidth` properties must always be less than `BufferHeight` and `BufferWidth` respectively.

`WindowLeft` must be less than `BufferWidth - WindowWidth` and `WindowTop` must be less than `BufferHeight - WindowHeight`.

`WindowLeft` and `WindowTop` are relative to the buffer.

To move the actual console window, [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4426/Console-Enhancements) article has a good example.

I have used some of your code and code from the CodeProject sample. You can set window location and size both in a single function. No need to set `Console.WindowHeight` and `Console.WindowWidth` again. This is how my class looks:

```
class Program
{
    const int SWP_NOZORDER = 0x4;
    const int SWP_NOACTIVATE = 0x10;

    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();


    [DllImport("user32")]
    static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter,
        int x, int y, int cx, int cy, int flags);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WindowWidth = 50;
        Console.WindowHeight = 3;
        Console.BufferWidth = 50;
        Console.BufferHeight = 3;
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkMagenta;

        var screen = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
        var width = screen.Width;
        var height = screen.Height;

        SetWindowPosition(100, height - 300, 500, 100);
        Console.Title = "My Title";
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.Write(" Press any key to close this window ...");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the console window location and size in pixels
    /// </summary>
    public static void SetWindowPosition(int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        SetWindowPos(Handle, IntPtr.Zero, x, y, width, height, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
    }

    public static IntPtr Handle
    {
        get
        {
            //Initialize();
            return GetConsoleWindow();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I keep wrestling with this error: `Additional information: The window position must be set such that the current window size fits within the console's buffer, and the numbers must not be negative.`

Comment: Good information, good code sample, but the first sentence is misleading: the question is all about _moving the window on the screen_.
I suggest you make it clear that, despite their names, setting `Console.WindowTop` and `Console.WindowWidth` does _not_ change the window's _position on screen_ and doing so cannot be done through the `Console` class.

Answer (score 34):

Note: Despite their names, **setting `Console.WindowLeft` and `Console.WindowTop` of the [`System.Console` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console(v=vs.110).aspx) does *not* change the window's *position on screen*.**
Instead, they position the visible part of the window relative to the (potentially larger) window *buffer* - **you cannot use type `System.Console` to change the position of console windows on the screen - you need to use the Windows API for that**.

---

The following is **code for a complete console application** that **positions its own window in the lower left corner of the screen, *respecting the location of the taskbar***.

Note:

- It *should* work with multi-monitor setups - positioning the window on the specific monitor (display, screen) it is (mostly) being displayed on - but I haven't personally verified it.
- **Only Windows API functions are used via P/Invoke declarations**, avoiding the need for referencing the WinForms assembly (`System.Windows.Forms`), which is not normally needed in *console* applications.

  - You'll see that a good portion of the code is devoted to P/Invoke signatures (declaration) for interfacing with the native Windows APIs; these were gratefully adapted from [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net)
  - The actual code in the `Main()` method is short by comparison.
- If you compile the code below from a console-application project in Visual Studio and run the resulting executable from a `cmd.exe` console window (Command Prompt), that console window should shift to the lower left corner of the (containing screen).

  - To verify the functionality while running from Visual Studio, place a breakpoint at the closing `}` and, when execution pauses, Alt-Tab to the console window to verify its position.

---

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; // To enable P/Invoke signatures.

public static class PositionConsoleWindowDemo
{

    // P/Invoke declarations.

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr MonitorFromWindow(IntPtr hwnd, uint dwFlags);

    const int MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY = 1;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool GetMonitorInfo(IntPtr hMonitor, ref MONITORINFO lpmi);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct MONITORINFO
    {
        public uint cbSize;
        public RECT rcMonitor;
        public RECT rcWork;
        public uint dwFlags;
        public static MONITORINFO Default
        {
            get { var inst= new MONITORINFO(); inst.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(inst); return inst; }
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct RECT
    {
        public int Left, Top, Right, Bottom;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct POINT
    {
        public int x, y;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool GetWindowPlacement(IntPtr hWnd, ref WINDOWPLACEMENT lpwndpl);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool SetWindowPlacement(IntPtr hWnd, [In] ref WINDOWPLACEMENT lpwndpl);

    const uint SW_RESTORE= 9;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct WINDOWPLACEMENT
    {
        public uint Length;
        public uint Flags;
        public uint ShowCmd;
        public POINT MinPosition;
        public POINT MaxPosition;
        public RECT NormalPosition;
        public static WINDOWPLACEMENT Default
        {
            get
            {
                var instance = new WINDOWPLACEMENT();
                instance.Length = (uint) Marshal.SizeOf(instance);
                return instance;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        // Get this console window's hWnd (window handle).
        IntPtr hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();

        // Get information about the monitor (display) that the window is (mostly) displayed on.
        // The .rcWork field contains the monitor's work area, i.e., the usable space excluding
        // the taskbar (and "application desktop toolbars" - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx)
        var mi = MONITORINFO.Default;
        GetMonitorInfo(MonitorFromWindow(hWnd, MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY), ref mi);

        // Get information about this window's current placement.
        var wp = WINDOWPLACEMENT.Default;
        GetWindowPlacement(hWnd, ref wp);

        // Calculate the window's new position: lower left corner.
        // !! Inexplicably, on W10, work-area coordinates (0,0) appear to be (7,7) pixels 
        // !! away from the true edge of the screen / taskbar.
        int fudgeOffset = 7;
        wp.NormalPosition = new RECT() {
            Left = -fudgeOffset,
            Top = mi.rcWork.Bottom - (wp.NormalPosition.Bottom - wp.NormalPosition.Top),
            Right = (wp.NormalPosition.Right - wp.NormalPosition.Left),
            Bottom = fudgeOffset + mi.rcWork.Bottom
        };

        // Place the window at the new position.
        SetWindowPlacement(hWnd, ref wp);

    }

}
```

Answer (score -3):

1. Run any console application
2. Click RMB on headline.
3. Choose properties option.
4. choose Position tab.
5. Uncheck box "Automatic choice"
6. Set console position as you want.

Comment: It was clear the OP was looking for a way to do it programmatically.